# Is there a more efficient algorithm to flatten an array?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, algorithm

I am aware of the *recursive* way to flatten a nested array.
There are several solutions on stackoverflow (both in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851548/flatten-nested-arrays-in-java) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266550/how-to-flatten-nested-array-in-javascript) - some using built in libraries).

But the time complexity of these solutions is O(n^2)! 
I was wondering if there is an algorithm which could do better.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: They look like O(n) where n is the number of elements. I don't see how you will get better than that.

Comment: Is n dimension of array you are referring to?, but If n is number of elements its considered O(n)

Comment: The answer from "Adam" in that JavaScript question you linked is linear, not quadratic. @VinceEmigh it's not reasonable when it's trivial to do it in linear time :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey well the versions that use some sort of array concatenation functions are not really linear, but doing it by building a single accumulator array is linear if you ignore the cost of a dynamically-sized array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are either mistaken or you define your *n* as the root square of number of elements to process.

All the sane solutions of the array flattening problem are O(n), where n depends on the total number of elements (because, essentially, you need to scan them all, each of them only once). Flattening an array is not an algorithmic problem, it's just the question of getting it in an "elegant" snippet.

Comment: I see. Please correct me if I am wrong, but is it safe to say that it is pseudo-polynomial then?

Comment: @KarthikVasishta big-O is always the highest order of the polynomial.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey

Comment: *"you need to scan them all, each of them **only once**"*. That's not true for Java. Since Java arrays are fixed-size, you have to pre-scan the arrays to find the total number of elements for the result, before you can start building it. Still *O(n)* though.

Comment: @Andreas: I appreciate your nit-pick :-) But if we interpret things at this level, the question is not really valid - there is no "array" in Javascript (unless you count the Typed Arrays API, which is not part of ECMA) - so the cost of just adding N elements to a javascript "array" probably gets us around  NlogN (to pay for growing the array). In my reply I assumed that the equivalent of Javascript "array" is Java's LinkedList :-)