# How to check if a two dimensional Array contains only digits

Tags: java, arrays

I got a two dimensional String array with only numbers in it;

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(temp));
[[1, 3, 1, 2], [2, 3, 2, 2], [5, 6, 7, 1], [3, 3, 1, 1]]
```

I need to check if the array contains only numbers, otherwise I will throw an exception.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(temp[0]).matches("[0-9]*")); - return false                           
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(temp[0]).matches("[0-9]+")); - return false
```

As far as I get, The code says that the array does not contains only numbers, because when converted to char the array is like :

```
[[, [, 1, ,,  , 3, ,,  , 1, ,,  , 2, ], ,,  , [, 2, ,,  , 3, ,,  , 2, ,,  , 2, ], ,,  , [, 5, ,,  , 6, ,,  , 7, ,,  , 1, ], ,,  , [, 3, ,,  , 3, ,,  , 1, ,,  , 1, ], ]]
```

How can I check if it contains only numbers?

Comment: There's a straightforward solution to this, but before I begin:  is there any reason that you're not just storing this as numbers from the get-go?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44909768/133203) then just attach an `allMatch` that checks whether they are numbers.

Comment: reason - technical assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first loop through your array. Since each element will be an array, loop through it. Then for each element (that should be a String) check if it's what you want.

To loop through your Array of arrays :

```
boolean arrayIsCorrect = true; //flag to know if array is correct
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) { //loop through the array of arrays
    for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++) { //loop through the sub-array array[i]
        if(!isCorrect(array[i][j])) {
            arrayIsCorrect = false;
            break; //optimization not required
        }
    }
    if(!arrayIsCorrect) { //optimization not required
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("Is the array correct ? " + arrayIsCorrect ); //print the result
```

In your question it's not clear if you want elements to be digit or numbers. In case of digit the function `isCorrect()` should look like :

```
public boolean isCorrect(String s) {
    return s.matches("[0-9]");
}
```

In case of number, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java/12569609#12569609)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a function that checks if it is numeric.

Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size();i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array.size();j++){
        if(temp.isNumeric(temp[i][j] == false)
        break;
    }
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String value) {
    boolean result;
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(value);
        result = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException excepcion) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but this is missing the part where you traverse the multidimensional array.

Comment: just go through the array with a loop

Comment: That won't work, traversing the array will give you arrays. Then you'd need to flatten it first (or do nested loops to check that your function always returns true), which is a whole lot different than your answer. That's what's missing, and it's an important part of the question.