# Changing the number of dimensions an Java array has

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way of changing the number of dimensions an array has, i.e making this

```
int[][] i = new int[3][3];
```

but using it like this

```
getArray(i); //where getArray only accepts one dimensional arrays
```

?

Comment: @StephenC yea, though I am confused on the object thing. How would that help (I am new the "Object" object type)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten nested arrays in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851548/flatten-nested-arrays-in-java)

Comment: @pkpnd - Not a dup.  This question is really about accessing, not converting / reshaping the array.  (Yes I know the OP says "changing" ... but that isn't what his example is doing ... by my interpretation of what a getter does.)

Comment: @AlexDukhan Do you want to transform `i` into a one-dimensional array, `int[9]`, so `getArray` operates on `int` elements? Or, do you want `getArray` to operate on the `int[]` elements contained inside `i`?

Comment: @pkpnd sort of. I would hope that I dont have to loose the second dimension, and as you said, can simply access it as 1D.

Comment: @AlexDukhan Can you provide a bit more context? Say, are you trying to get an element at index `5`, which would really be `i[1][2]`?

Comment: @pkpnd No, I want do this sort of thing: Int getArray (int [] array) { do stuff to i}; and then have an: int[][] i = stuff; and then do: getArray(i)

Comment: That's exactly my question, _what stuff are you doing to the array_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the number of dimensions in a Java array or array type.

But you can make use of the fact that a Java array is an object ... and subtyping .. and declare a `getArray` method like this:

```
 Object getArray(Object[], ...) { .... }
```

You can call this method on a `int[][]` instance, but a runtime typecast is needed to cast the result to an `int[]`.

For example:

```
Object getArray(Object[] array, int i) { return array[i]; }

int[][] big = new int[3][3];
int[] slice = (int[]) getArray(big, 0);
```

---

On the other hand, if you are really asking about how to **flatten** a multi-dimensional array into a 1-D array, the `getArray` method needs to allocate a new array, fill it from the original and return it.

Note you would be returning a brand new array that is unconnected to the original one.   And copying an N x N .... x N array is expensive.

For more details: [Flatten nested arrays in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851548/flatten-nested-arrays-in-java)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, you're just down-casting it. I'll use that in my code. Thank you for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

Java is statically-typed language. This means that you cannot change a variable's type at runtime. But in this particular case you can simply use the following invocation:

```
getArray(i[2]); // put anything between 0 and (outerArrayLength-1) instead of 2 here
```