# Flatten nested string arrays

Tags: java

I'm trying to use streams to flatten a multidimensional string array. I could do it with loops but streams seems to be the more idiomatic way. I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851548/flatten-nested-arrays-in-java) but that uses integer specific methods. The following returns an object array instead of the expected `String[]`.

```
String[][][] sources = new String[][][]{
           {{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"}}
           {{"g","h","i"},{"j","k","l"}}
};
String[] values = Arrays.stream(sources[0])
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .toArray();
```

Comment: `.toArray(String[]::new)`.

Comment: "instead of the expected string[]" had you read [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray--), you wouldn't be expecting that.

Comment: Thanks, I totally overlooked that and thought the problem was upstream

Comment: your array should be an array of char `char[][][] sources = new char[][][]` not of String!!

Comment: @YCF_L or the array elements are actually declared with `"`s instead of `'`s.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the example wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your current example compile, the `toArray` should be:

```
String[] values = Arrays.stream(sources[0])
                        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                        .toArray(String[]::new); // <----------------------
```

If you want to do it for `sources` you'll need to use  `flatMap` twice then collect to an array with `.toArray(String[]::new)`:

```
String[] values = Arrays.stream(sources)
                        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                        .toArray(String[]::new);
```