# Unhandled checked Exception while flattening an Array of Objects recursively using Streams in Java 8

Tags: java, recursion, java-stream, flatten

I am trying to flatten an array of Objects recursively.

For Example

*Input:*

```
Object[] array = { 1, 2, new Object[]{ 3, 4, new Object[]{ 5 }, 6, 7 }, 8, 9, 10 };
```

*Output:*

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

While making the recursive call, I am getting a compilation:

```
unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

How can I fix it?

*My code:*

```
public static Integer[] flatten(Object[] inputArray) throws Exception {
    
    //Convert inputArray to stream of object
    Stream<Object> stream = Arrays.stream(inputArray);
    //Recursively using flat map flatten the array by mapping each element to a stream
    stream.flatMap(o -> o instanceof Object[] ? flatten((Object[])o) : Stream.of(o));
    Integer[] flattenedArray = stream.toArray(Integer[]::new);
    return flattenedArray;
}
```

Comment: Just calling flatMap does nothing.  You need to use the Stream that flatMap returns.

Comment: Just remove the `throws Exception`

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues:

- Type `Exception` is a *checked exception*. The problem is that none of the built-in JDK functions declares to throw a *checked exception*, which imposes restriction on their implementations. Therefore, the simplest solution would be to remove throws clause, that would allow to invoke `flatten()` recursively from the stream without any complaints.
- The second problem stems from the need to coerce the elements to the `Integer` type. I would advise providing `Class<T>` as an argument it would make the solution both clean an versatile. Or alternatively, return type can be changed to `Object[]` (*chose the option which is more suitable depending on your needs*).

Let's start with a simple implementation that returns array of type `Object[]`. In order to implement flattening logic I've used Java 16 [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) since it's more suitable when you need to incorporate imperative logic into the stream.

```
public static Object[] flatten(Object[] inputArray) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(inputArray)
        .mapMulti((element, consumer) -> {
            if (element instanceof Object[] arr) for (var next: flatten(arr)) consumer.accept(next);
            else consumer.accept(element);
        })
        .toArray();
}
```

If we switch to generic implementation, the return type needs to be changed to a `List<T>` (or `Collection<T>`), otherwise we run into a problem of creating a generic array. Generics and array do not play well together and it highly advisable to favor Collections over arrays, hence I'll go with `List<T>` as a return type.

```
public static <T> List<T> flatten(Object[] inputArray, Class<T> tClass) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(inputArray)
        .<T>mapMulti((element, consumer) -> {
            if (element instanceof Object[] arr) for (var next: flatten(arr, tClass)) consumer.accept(next);
            else consumer.accept(tClass.cast(element));
        })
        .toList();
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] array = { 1, 2, new Object[]{ 3, 4, new Object[]{ 5 }, 6, 7 }, 8, 9, 10 };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flatten(array)));

    Object[] string = { "A", "B", new Object[]{ "C", "D", new Object[]{ "E" }, "F", "G" }, "H", "I", "J" };
    
    List<String> flattenedString = flatten(string, String.class);

    System.out.println(flattenedString);
}
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]
```

### Update

Here's another way to solve this problem using `Stream.flatMap()`, built upon [*this answer by @Holger*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44909768/2711488).

For that, we can split the logic into two parts: a helper-method that performs recursive flattening and a method that generates the result of the required type.

And, well, since it's another solution I've decided to change the resulting type to `T[]` (in case if you really need an array as a result). There's no clean and easy way to create a generic array which should be exposed to the outside context (in this case, creating `Object[]` and casting to `T[]` would result in `ClassCastException`). To address this issue, we can employ the Reflection API to allocate the array in memory via `Array.newInstance()` and then type cast it.

```
public static <T> T[] flatten(Object[] inputArray, Class<T> tClass) {
    
    return flattenAsStream(inputArray, tClass)
        .toArray(n -> (T[]) Array.newInstance(tClass, n));
}

public static <T> Stream<T> flattenAsStream(Object[] inputArray, Class<T> tClass) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(inputArray)
        .flatMap(e -> e instanceof Object[] arr ?
            flattenAsStream(arr, tClass) : Stream.of(tClass.cast(e))
        );
}
```

Comment: You can [easily flatten an array non-imperatively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44909768/2711488) and considering the non-lazy nature of `mapMulti`, I wouldn’t use a `mapMulti` approach for arbitrary nested arrays.

Comment: @Holger That's a fair point, I forgot about non-laziness of `mapMulti`. Updated the answer.